# How can I dismiss an Angular Snackbar(Ref) in an idle subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have implemented ng-idle in my application. When the user is going idle there will shown an Angular Material Snackbar with the countdown (this is already working). When the user moves his mouse (or clicks or any other interaction) it needs to dismiss the opened snackbar.

Class/Service (where all code except the custom Snackbar is located):

```
openSnackbar = null;
constructor(private idle: Idle, private snackbar: MatSnackBar){}
```

Code when last 5 seconds will starts to do an action:

```
this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => {
    this.openSnackbar = this.snackbar.openFromComponent(CountdownSnackbarComponent, {
       duration: 5000
    });
});
```

Snackbar component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'countdown-snackbar',
  template: `{{ secondsLeft }} seconds left to do an action!`,
})
    export class CountdownSnackbarComponent {
          secondsLeft = '5';
        
          constructor() {}
    }
```

Code when user does an action while last 5 seconds were already started:

```
this.idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
  this.idleState = 'No longer idle.';
  this.openSnackbar.dismiss();
}
```

So if a user does an action (such as clicking) the Snackbar needs to be dismissed. However with the code above, the Snackbar will not be dismissed but it keeps the snackbar open even longer than the duration that has been added to the config of the snackbar.

How can I close the snackbar in the (onIdleEnd) subscribe function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try dismiss method with reference directly from the service

```
this.idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
  this.idleState = 'No longer idle.';
  this.snackbar.dismiss();
}
```